# Geodesics in polyhedral graphs

Tags: graph-theory, dg.differential-geometry

Let  $e = \lbrace u,v\rbrace$, $e' = \lbrace v,u'\rbrace$ be edges of an undirected graph $G$ and $ee'$ be the path from $u$ through $v$ to $u'$. The following defintions make sense for *every* graph and thus are purely combinatorial:

> **Definition 1**: $ee'$ is a **pre-geodesic** when it is the unique shortest path between $u$ and $u'$
>
> **Definition 2**: A pre-geodesic $ee'$ is a **geodesic** when there is no other edge $f$ through $v$ such that $ef$ or $e'f$ is a pre-geodesic.

The first condition is motivated by the fact that geodesics in differential geometry are locally *shortest* paths and as such locally *unique*. It prevents the graph

[image]

from having geodesics.

The second condition reflects the fact, that geodesics usually do not “split”. It prevents the graph

[image]

from having geodesics.

But now, let's restrict to **[polyhedral graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedral_graph)**. I wonder if it's true for polyhedral graphs that only a small number of patterns of geodesics going through a given vertex $v$ are possible:

> - Which patterns?
> - How to prove this?

Have a look at this gallery of vertices $v$ (grey, drawn with *all* their neighbours) with degree at most 6 and at most three geodesics (red, blue, green) passing through them (all the other vertices may or must have *further* neighbours):

[image]

> - Is this gallery essentially complete?
> - If so: how to prove it?

Otherwise:

> - Is there a polyhedral graph with a vertex of degree 7 with a geodesic
>   passing through it?
> - Is there a polyhedral graph with a vertex with four geodesics passing through it?

Comment: Am I interpreting this correctly? Every pre-geodesic, and therefore every geodesic, is exactly two edges long...?  In your square example, label three consecutive vertices $u,v,u'$.  So $(u,v,u')$ is a pre-geodesic.  You claim it is not a geodesic.  But surely there is no other edge $f$ incident to $v$, so it seems $(u,v,u')$ *is* a geodesic according to your definition.

Comment: @Joseph: To your first question: no, two geodesic edges are supposed to be the building blocks of longer geodesics. I only wanted to make the 2-edge-case clear in advance. To your second: Two consecutive edges are *not* a pre-geodesic because they are not a *unique* shortest path.